# Groupby on python without aggegation

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I am having problem on selecting observations on each unique index.
I would like to extract data from each group like the following table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWfD4.png)

The table consists of 12 unique months and they repeat 10 times for 10 years. I would like to group  by their unique months and see the distribution of 12 different months. So the final table would be having 12 columns of 12 months and 10 rows of years.

I am thinking of starting from groupby function and use for loop to print out different groups.

```
data1 = data.groupby(by='month')


for name, group in data1:
print(name)
print(group)
```

Comment: You should give an example of the output you finally want. The description you gave is blurred.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.